# Disable Antd Datepicker tooltip

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, tooltip, antd

I'm using Antd Datepicker in my website. We get an array of numbers representing disabled dates from an external api and show only the dates in the datepicker(no month, year etc). The date selection is for a monthly subscription and the user just selects the day of the month he wants for the money to be deducted from his account, for this purpose we have gone with November 2015 as default value in our datepicker(since it has 1st as a Sunday). Now when a user hovers over the date it shows [DD, November 2015]. I don't want the tool tip to be visible to the user as it creates a bad UX.

```
<DatePicker
  defaultPickerValue="{moment('2015-11-01')}"
  dropdownClassName="c-datepicker-dropdown"
  disabledDate="{(current) => this.disabledDates(current, this.props.frequency_data)}"
  showToday={false}
  allowClear={false}
  onChange="{(date) => this.handleLogic(date)}"
  style="{{ width: 132 }}"
/>
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-mrbhp?file=/index.js) I want the tooltip onhover to be removed

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ0o3.png)

Comment: I don't see the possibility of a tooltip showing with this code. Can you maybe share a bit more to reproduce what you are asking. Maybe on codesandbox.io

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to hide the date tooltip, since the date tooltip onHover is the browser's default behavior. The date tooltip results from the dates being anchor elements with a `title` attribute. 

You would have to essential remove the `title` attribute from all the date links to in order to hide the tooltip.

Comment: Is there any way to change the behaviour of the tooltip.. maybe give it a delay of more than 10s so that it isn't that obvious or just show the date in the tooltip[.. i just need a quick fix for now.. will have to revisit later to refactor our logic of date selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antd provides a way to style how one renders each date through the dateRender option. Adding a custom render function did the trick for me.

```
<DatePicker
          defaultPickerValue="{moment('2015-11-01')}"
          format="Do"
          dateRender="{(current) => this.renderCustomDate(current)}"
          dropdownClassName="c-datepicker-dropdown"
          disabledDate="{(current) => this.disabledDates(current,this.props.frequency_data.MONTHLY)}"
          showToday={false}                                            
          style="{{ width: 132 }}"
          />
```

Here's my custom function. (Title is empty, hence the tooltip is not visible)

```
 renderCustomDate(current) {
    return (
      <div className="ant-calendar-date" title="">
        {current.date()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may fix the issue, but it's a bit ugly because the pointer seems to flicker while hovering.

```
td.ant-calendar-cell {
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.ant-calendar-cell:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tooltip, but the title attribute on the `<td>` element. If you want to disable this, you can do the following. Tested and working in antd version 5.12.5.

```
const cellRender = (current) => {
  return (
    <div title="" className="ant-picker-cell">
      <div title="" className="ant-picker-cell ant-picker-cell-in-view">
        <div title="" className="ant-picker-cell-inner">
          {current.date()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
<DatePicker cellRender={cellRender} picker="day" />
```